# Xcode 5 0 targets, missing base SDK - how to recover (only My Mac option)

Tags: xcode

For no apparent reason (nothing changed since debug build yesterday) I now have no target in the Xcode panel. In file section the top heading says '0 targets, missing base sdk'; the Project is listed but the Targets is blank.
When I select Build Settings for the project I see a set of options previously never seen (presumably Mac settings?). There is no Base SDK entry (most forum posts on this subject advise finding this and changing it to 'latest iOS' - this I cannot do because the entry is not there).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**You have deleted your target.** First thing I would suggest is to **check out the last working version** from whatever version control you're using and either look for differences or just revert.

Of course, that assumes you're using version control.

If you're not, start. Immediately. And then AFTER you have done that, make and configure a new target :)

Comment: "make and configure a new target" - how is this done? This is what is causing me grief!!

Comment: In the screenshot you've attached it says "Add target...". Click that.